# counting the number of elements with the value Z in data frame in r

Tags: r, aggregate

I want to count the number of elements with the value Z.

I will give an example of what I need.

I have a huge number of tags (millions) stored in a data frame and they are in the form < X >.

as shown in the figure below. I need to get the count of each tag to find the top 10 tags (The tags that were mentioned the most).

The example :

[image]

The output I need is :

[image]

Note : Im beginner in R, so I need the simplest way.

My attempt : I tried the function table() but it looks like it works for numbers. 
I tried group_by() and I did not get the result that  want.
sample of data set :

```
DF <- data.frame(Tag=c("<C++><Java>","<java><python><javascript>","<java><C++>","<Json><PHP>","<PHP><Java>"))

                         Tag
1                <C++><Java>
2 <java><python><javascript>
3                <java><C++>
4                <Json><PHP>
5                <PHP><Java>
```

Comment: Can you then upload `dput(head(data))` The one you uploaded as an image. Upload it in data format

Comment: Please post (part of) your sample data using `dput`; a screenshot is not useful, as it requires potential respondents to manually type in your sample data.

Comment: I added a sample of the data set, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution in base R; in my opinion, there's no need for a load of additional libraries in this case.

```
table(unlist(strsplit(gsub("(^<|>$)", "", DF$Tag), "><")));
#       C++       java       Java javascript       Json        PHP     python
#         2          2          2          1          1          2          1
```

Or if you want to ignore capitalisation you could convert all tags to lower-case:

```
table(tolower(unlist(strsplit(gsub("(^<|>$)", "", DF$Tag), "><"))));
#       c++       java javascript       json        php     python
#         2          4          1          1          2          1
```

As `data.frame`

```
as.data.frame(table(tolower(unlist(strsplit(gsub("(^<|>$)", "", DF$Tag), "><")))))
#        Var1 Freq
#1        c++    2
#2       java    4
#3 javascript    1
#4       json    1
#5        php    2
#6     python    1
```

Explanation: Remove `"<"` and `">"` from beginning and end, respectively; `strsplit` on `"><"`, and use `table` to count occurrences.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `stringi`, `dplyr`, and `tidytext` packages, you could do the following. You can extract the computer language names with `stri_extract_all_regex()` and split each string and create a data frame with `unnest_tokens()`. Then, you count how many times each language appeared in the data set.

```
DF %>%
unnest_tokens(input = Tag, output = language, token = stri_extract_all_regex,
              pattern = "(?<=\\<)[^<>]*(?=\\>)", to_lower = TRUE) %>%
count(language, sort = TRUE)

  language       n
  <chr>      <int>
1 java           4
2 c++            2
3 php            2
4 javascript     1
5 json           1
6 python         1
```

Comment: Another option is `DF %>% separate_rows(Tag, sep = "<|>") %>% filter(nzchar(Tag)) %>% count(tolower(Tag))`

Comment: @akrun That is simpler!

Comment: There is a filtering step afterwards which you don't need

Comment: @akrun It would be nice to have an argument like `omit_empty` in `separate_rows()`.

Comment: Yeah, that would be great which would take `TRUE` or `FALSE`

Comment: @akrun Yeah I realized that too. I do not know why. At least my code is generating the expected outcome, I suppose. A random thing. I try not to fight.

Comment: It also happens sometimes, probably somebody who wants to use their voting rights from getting rusted

Comment: @akrun Yeah probably. The important thing for me is to learn from questions and help others as much as I can. Staying focusing on positive things is the key. (At least I have an upvote left!)

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)
DF%>%mutate(Freq=1)%>%
     unnest_tokens(Tag,Tag,"regex",pattern="<|>|\\n")%>%group_by(Tag)%>%
     summarise(count=n())%>%arrange(desc(count))
# A tibble: 6 x 2
         Tag count
       <chr> <int>
1       java     4
2        c++     2
3        php     2
4 javascript     1
5       json     1
6     python     1
```

To do this in base R:
You will need to `split`, then `trim` the whitespaces and table and sort in a descending order

```
sort(table(trimws(unlist(strsplit(gsub("<(.*?)>(R?)","\\U\\1 ",DF$Tag,perl = T)," ")))),T)

      JAVA        C++        PHP JAVASCRIPT       JSON     PYTHON 
         4          2          2          1          1          1
```